# I need to be able to save my data on my Ubuntu on USB

Tags: usb

I run Ubuntu on a USB, but it doesn't save my data. Is there a way to save my data?

Answer (score 0):

Create your Live USB stick in Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator by selecting the option "Stored in reserved extra space."  Select the amount of extra space you want to use onthe USB stick to store your files and data.

(As a tip, I like to use the KDE version of Startup Disk Creator, usb-creator-kde, because it seems to work better for me).

Another option is to insert a second USB stick while running Ubuntu from the (first) Live USB stick.  Save your files to the second USB stick.